# Windows7 Hosts Running insanely slow in VirtualBox

Tags: server, virtualbox, virtualization

Hi I am a running a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 16.04 with ssh, kvm, webmin, and virtualbox installed the System itself is a HP G5 DL580 with 2x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7430 @ 2.13GHz, 8 cores and 48gb of ram.

The virtual machine has 2 cores, and 10gb of ram yet rarely goes under 50% cpu usage at idle and only ever for a moment never any usage puts it up to 100%. Here is my Virtualmachine config, everything else is default at the moment.

```
    ** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
    ** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application
    ** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect.
    ** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes.
    -->
    <VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.15-windows">
  <Machine uuid="{cc8bfddd-d263-4b77-b8f6-d48eb7f7aee8}" name="win7" OSType="Windows7_64" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2017-10-03T06:53:31Z">
    <MediaRegistry>
      <HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{a79fdfdc-11cb-42a1-b99a-2787bb29c4c8}" location="win7.vhd" format="VHD" type="Normal"/>
      </HardDisks>
      <DVDImages>
        <Image uuid="{a5fdb0fb-56ee-466d-ab9b-3c3aefe60d21}" location="H:/Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate (64 Bit)/Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate (64 Bit).iso"/>
      </DVDImages>
    </MediaRegistry>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="462,132,640,480,max"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RestrictedRuntimeDevicesMenuActions" value="HardDrives"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RestrictedRuntimeMachineMenuActions" value="SaveState,PowerOff"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/ScaleFactor" value="1"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/StatusBar/IndicatorOrder" value="HardDisks,OpticalDisks,FloppyDisks,Network,USB,SharedFolders,Display,VideoCapture,Features,Mouse,Keyboard"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <Hardware>
      <CPU count="2">
        <PAE enabled="true"/>
        <LongMode enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="true"/>
      </CPU>
      <Memory RAMSize="10635"/>
      <HID Pointing="USBTablet"/>
      <Paravirt provider="Default"/>
      <Boot>
        <Order position="1" device="HardDisk"/>
        <Order position="2" device="None"/>
        <Order position="3" device="None"/>
        <Order position="4" device="None"/>
      </Boot>
      <Display VRAMSize="85"/>
      <RemoteDisplay enabled="false">
        <VRDEProperties>
          <Property name="TCP/Ports" value="3389"/>
        </VRDEProperties>
      </RemoteDisplay>
      <BIOS>
        <IOAPIC enabled="true"/>
      </BIOS>
      <USB>
        <Controllers>
          <Controller name="OHCI" type="OHCI"/>
        </Controllers>
      </USB>
      <Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027147C8B" cable="true" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <InternalNetwork name="intnet"/>
            <NATNetwork name="NatNetwork"/>
          </DisabledModes>
          <BridgedInterface name="enp6s0"/>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="1" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="2" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="3" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="4" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="5" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="6" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
        <Adapter slot="7" cable="true" type="82540EM"/>
      </Network>
      <AudioAdapter controller="HDA" driver="DirectSound" enabled="false"/>
      <RTC localOrUTC="UTC"/>
      <GuestProperties>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="en_US" timestamp="1506972787820719400" flags=""/>
      </GuestProperties>
    </Hardware>
    <StorageControllers>
      <StorageController name="SATA" type="AHCI" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="false" Bootable="true" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">
        <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" hotpluggable="false" port="0" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{a79fdfdc-11cb-42a1-b99a-2787bb29c4c8}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
        <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" hotpluggable="false" port="1" device="0"/>
      </StorageController>
    </StorageControllers>
  </Machine>
</VirtualBox>
```

Or see it here: https://pastebin.com/C3p6y9ni

Comment: I think it's problem in Windows host (hardware limitations or settings issue). Did you installed VirtualBox Extension Pack and Linux Guest Additions?

Comment: Sorry I meant windows guests, ubuntu server is the host OS. No I have not installed any extension packs, I did not know I needed to?

Comment: ExtensionPacks optimize performance at Virtualbox Application, GuestAdditions optimize guest performance. [Look them here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html)

Comment: Thank you very much guest additions made an instant improvement on the machine, 2 questions though if I may, is the vbox extensions just "virtualbox-ext-pack" that I can get through apt or is there more that I am missin, and out of curiosity do you know how to insert the additions cd via the terminal when the machine is running? Thank you.

Comment: GuestAdditions is embedded in VirtualBox App, Just [follow this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36500_01/E36502/html/qs-guest-additions.html)